# Firefox Reader Mode lost my form input

Tags: firefox-for-android, buttons, reading

I accidentally clicked on the stupid Reader Mode button in Firefox while I was typing into a form on a webpage, then quickly tapped it again to return to normal mode, but it reloaded the page, losing everything I typed. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1225124 doesn't work because I can't access about:config (blank (white) page), and https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1300502 doesn't help with that. Is there any way to either disable this useless feature or prevent it from losing my data, and/or restore what I typed this time?

To the Firefox developers, here are your options:

1. Move the Reader Mode button into the 3-dot menu or somewhere else that requires multiple taps
2. Don't reload the page when toggling Reader Mode
3. Save the page state (especially form data) before entering Reader Mode and restore it when exiting
4. Provide an option to remove Reader Mode or do any of the above

Firefox Daylight, 94.1.2 (Build #2015844587), AC: 94.0.12, e5eb726f81, GV: 94.0-20211028161635, AS: 85.4.0, 2021-11-08T21:26:04.605951, on Android 12.

Comment: Please write the suggestion for Firefox directly to Firefox, not here. There's very little to no chance Firefox developers will read this on here.

Comment: Good idea, posted as a reply for now: https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix/issues/17832#issuecomment-980789689